# How to find documentation for Material UI components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am struggling to find proper documentation for MUI components. When I try to copy an example from the site that I like, I struggle to adapt to my needs. many props that are used in these examples I can't find the docs of on the official site, or am I stupid and can't read?

My example:

```
    <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{
            '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
    >
```

The props here I can't find docs for, and the content of the sx prop "&. MUI text field-root".

Am trying here to change on of the textfields to a select menu but I don't know whyit can't inherit the styling.

```
        <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{
            '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
    >
        <div>
            
                

            <TextField
                required
                id="outlined-required"
                label="Required"
                defaultValue="Hello World"
            />
            <Select
                labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                id="demo-simple-select"
                value={age}
                label="Age"
                onChange={handleChange}
                sx={{
                    '& .MuiSelect-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
                }}
            >
                <MenuItem>Select an age</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
     </div>    
  </Box>
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah MUI docs are not the best for me too.

In the Box example you shared, by going to the respective MUI doc page, it says at the bottom of the page:

"As a CSS utility, the Box component also supports all system properties. You can use them as props directly on the component. ".

By clicking on the "system" blue link you can see many other props (used in the Box component) and their description.
Also, don't forget to check if your MUI version is the same as the one you are checking in the docs. I always have that issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are broken down into Demos and API

Demo page for the Box component:

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/

API page for the box component:

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/box/

Note that link to the API docs is at the bottom of each demo page.

In the case you are looking at, the `sx` prop is actually documented in the demo page:

> All system properties are available via the sx prop. In addition, the sx prop allows you to specify any other CSS rules you may need. Here's an example of how you can use it:

But canonical reference should always be the API documentation:

> sx    Array<func
> | object
> | bool>
> | func
> | object
> The system prop that allows defining system overrides as well as additional CSS styles. See the `sx` page for more details.

And this documentation links to further information about `sx`

https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/

Answer (score 2):

you can see and struggle with MUI components in https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining more.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should have on any MUI component a link to the API specification, which can in some cases lead to other specifications like [system](https://mui.com/system/properties/) properties.

Reading an API is always like a rabbit hole :)

FYI: here is the link to the API for the Box component (https://mui.com/material-ui/api/box/)